# Is it a good way to solve sum of last & first digit?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I solved https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW004 by following way:

```
print(*[int(i[0])+int(i[-1]) for i in [list(str(input())) for _ in range(int(input()))]], sep='\n')
```

Is it a good way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly a way to solve it... what does *good* mean - does it pass the test?

Use a loop, forcing it on one line doesn't make this any quicker, just less readable. `input()` already returns a string and you can index it without turning it into a `list`, e.g.:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    i = input()
    print(int(i[0])+int(i[-1]))
```

You could use `operator.itemgetter()` to get the values you need, e.g.:

```
import operator as op
fl = op.itemgetter(0, -1)

for _ in range(int(input())):
    print(sum(map(int, fl(input()))))
```

An alternative more mathematical way to solve it:

```
In []:
import math

flsum = lambda x: x//(10**int(math.log10(x))) + x%10

for _ in range(int(input())):
    print(flsum(int(input())))

Out[]:
5
5
5
```

Comment: it passes the test